# Does CompletableFuture have any thenX method accept supplier?

Tags: java, lambda, callback, java-8

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html It shows CompletableFuture has the following thenX methods:

```
thenAccept(Consumer<? super T> action)
thenApply(Function<? super T,? extends U> fn)
thenRun(Runnable action)
```

I'm wondering what to do if I want to append a supplier (does not accept parameter but returns value) to a callback chain made by CompletableFuture?

Comment: As you can see from the javadoc you linked, no. Just use one of the existing methods and ignore the parameter.

Comment: What good would a supplier do? I don't see a reason why I would ever want to have a supplier as callback. Callbacks don't supply, they consume.

Comment: For example, I want to start a couple of async request functions and tracking them sequentially, each of the requests relies of the success of the tracker function of the previous request. In such case, the request function takes no input but has output (request Id), the tracker function takes request Id as input but has no output. So it is a list of supplier->consumer->supplier->consumer... What should I do in this case?

Comment: If you have a list of supplier->consumer->supplier->consumer and want to have this sequentially, simply write a method to do this and call the method in a CompletableFuture/FutureTask/Thread. This just is not a use case for CompletableFuture. If you want to do it in parallel, you are on CompletableFuture terrain. In that case, create multiple CompletableFutures, each encompassing a supplier->consumer pair, and create a monitoring object via CompletableFuture.allOf.

Comment: `.thenRun( () -> consumer.accept(supplier.get()) )`, which greatly shows how nonsensical the use of `CompletableFuture` is here. You can just run your entire sequential code like `CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> { consumer1.accept(supplier1.get()); consumer2.accept(supplier2.get()); consumer3.accept(supplier3.get()); } );`, but this could be done with *any* executor…

Comment: @Holger, except that way work will not be interleaved, as it might be when using the `*Async` methods.

Comment: @acelent: which is exactly [the OP’s intention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823792/does-completablefuture-have-any-thenx-method-accept-supplier?noredirect=1#comment63112172_37823792): “*each of the requests relies of the success of the tracker function of the previous request*”. The OP *wants* sequential execution…

Comment: @Holger, I was under the impression that the op was using `CompletableFuture` for more than chaining functions, but I admit I may have assumed too much.